# How to get the selected string from my log file using cut

Tags: bash, cut

This is my Log text:

```
03/17/2014 13:48:40.016- null - PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:Virus infected content detected while scanning file; File name: 2MBVirusTextFile.txt
```

From the above Log text i want to get the middle string 
i.e:

```
Virus infected content detected while scanning file
```

How do i get only this string ?

I have written the below code:

```
result=`tail  /home/eng/Shellscripts/result.txt | grep "PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:" | cut -f1 -d";"  `
echo "$result"
```

Output:

```
03/17/2014 13:48:40.016- null - PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:Virus infected content detected while scanning file
```

Comment: What language are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
tail result.txt | grep -o "PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:[^;]*" | cut -d: -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a `awk` version with multiple delimiters:

```
awk -F"[:;]" '{print $4}'
```

It looks for the 4th field based on two possible delimiters: `;` or `:`.

This `awk` version would allow you to also bypass the `grep` step:

```
result=$(tail /home/eng/Shellscripts/result.txt | awk -F"[:;]" '/PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:/ {print $4}')
```

---

In case you want to use `cut`, take the `:` delimiter and get the 4th element, and then the 1st based on the `;` delimiter:

```
cut -d':' -f4 file | cut -d';' -f1
```

All together:

```
result=$(tail /home/eng/Shellscripts/result.txt | grep "PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:" | cut -d: -f4 | cut -d';' -f1)
```

Comment: If he doesn't want the “; File name” (as he said), he'll need a 2nd `cut` or use something else, e.g. `awk`.

Comment: Yes, @Emmet, I noticed and was just updating. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the response...i got it now

Comment: yes it is working...i did not know that we need to accept it..anyways i did that now. Thank you

Comment: @user3429026 well you accepted another answer, but no problem if that one also works to you.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the given search string will be identical on all occurrences you could use bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

In the following examples I assume that a variable named `result` will contain the string `03/17/2014 13:48:40.016- null - PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:Virus infected content detected while scanning file; File name: 2MBVirusTextFile.txt`.

One possibility would be to use [substring expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion):

```
$ result="03/17/2014 13:48:40.016- null - PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:Virus infected content detected while scanning file; File name: 2MBVirusTextFile.txt"

$ result="${result:51:51}"
$ echo "$result"
Virus infected content detected while scanning file
```

The first value represents an offset starting from the beginning of the string, the second value describes the length starting at the end of the offset.

A second possibility could be to use [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal):

```
$ result="03/17/2014 13:48:40.016- null - PFM_DIP_SERVER_001:Virus infected content detected while scanning file; File name: 2MBVirusTextFile.txt"

# Remove everything from the beginning of the string
# until the first occurence of "001:"
$ result="${result#*001:}"
$ echo "$result"
Virus infected content detected while scanning file; File name: 2MBVirusTextFile.txt

# Remove everything from the end of the string
# until the first occurence of ";"
$ result="${result%;*}"
$ echo "$result"
Virus infected content detected while scanning file
```